# ConstraintLayout Keyframe animations in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, keyframe

I have followed the tutorial in Android docs for Keyframe animations in ConstraintLayouts [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#keyframe_animations), and it seems to work pretty fine in Activities. But I can't get it to work in a Fragment. Anyone have any idea why doesn't this work in Fragments, or what should be done within a Fragment to make KF anims work? It just seems that final layout just kicks in with no transition at all.

I have tried calling the animation in various steps of a Fragment lifecycle, with no difference at all, even tried adding a hard delay manually, but `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(clRoot);` seems to be completely ignored. I have even tried doing something like this:

```
AutoTransition autoTransition = new AutoTransition();
autoTransition.setDuration(3000);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(clRoot, autoTransition);
```

And `beginDelayedTransition` still gets completely ignored in Fragments.
And the final layout just gets loaded with no animation or transition or anything.

I've tried searching for the web and stacokoverflow high and wide and can't seem to find any clue on the solution to this, but if you did please nod me in the right direction.

Some examples below.

start_frame_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_root"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.phone_activity.phone.SubmitFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_splash"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_phone_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_m"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiet_phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Your phone number" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bounds_xl"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_phone_number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

final_frame_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:id="@+id/cl_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    tools:context=".ui.phone_activity.phone.SubmitFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bounds_l"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_splash"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_phone_number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_phone_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_xl"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_xl"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bounds_m"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_submit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiet_phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            style="@style/TextViewPrimary"
            android:hint="Your phone number" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bounds_l"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/bounds_xxxl"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/bounds_xxxl"
        style="@style/ButtonMain"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And code in SubmitFragment

```
@BindView(R.id.cl_root)
ConstraintLayout clRoot;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_frame_layout, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    return rootView;
}
```

And the animation method

```
public void animateEntry() {
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.load(getContext(), R.layout.final_frame_layout);
    // clRoot is R.id.cl_root (root ConstraintLayout)
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(clRoot);
    constraintSet.applyTo(clRoot);
}
```

Alternatively I've tried something like this too

```
public void animateEntry() {
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.load(getContext(), R.layout.final_frame_layout);
    AutoTransition autoTransition = new AutoTransition();
    autoTransition.setDuration(3000);
    // clRoot is R.id.cl_root (root ConstraintLayout)
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(clRoot, autoTransition);
    constraintSet.applyTo(clRoot);
}
```

Any idea, fix, solution?

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to animate? A fragment transition or a Fragment's layout?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Views withing the fragment layout. One imageView and few TextViews. The same as the tutorial has done, I have a starting frame layout, and a final frame layout. but it looks like not working inside of a Fragment. When I try doing the same thing within an Activity it works fine.

Comment: What method(s) of the fragment are you using to trigger the transition? You mention `various steps of a Fragment lifecycle...` which ones specifically. To be frank, i'm not sure what the problem is, I haven't tried that demo, but I'm curious because there shouldn't be a problem with this.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've tried in onStart, in onResume, I've even tried adding manual sleep before the trigger. The Fragment definitely picks up the starting layout, and moves to final one. But the problem is there is no animation, no transition or anything, it just ignores delayed transition and just switches from starting layout to final layout. I have expected it to work simply as it does in the Activity, but it does not.

Comment: If you happen to have a sample reproducible problem, I'd love to check it out :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini thanks for the offer. I have edited the question to contain more details with some code sampling.

Comment: did you fix it, I have the same problem

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim nope. I've given up on this idea in a fragment. Seems like it doesn't work outside Activity.